# Ant task to automate the start of my server and application

Tags: ant

I want to write Ant task to automate the task of starting my server and then open Internet Explorer with the URL of my application.

Obviously I have to execute the `startServer` task first and then `startApplication` task.

But Ant is not coming out of `startServer` task even after starting the server to execute `startApplication` task.

Basically I want Ant to understand that `startServer` will not end and ANT has to come out of `startServer` task and `runstartApplication` task while startServer task is running in background.

Comment: Can you post the `startServer` task?

Comment: <target name="runJBoss" > 
      <exec executable="${jboss.startup.bat}" />
 </target>
 
 <target name="startApplication">
  <exec executable="${internetexp}" spawn="true">
      <arg value="${myurl}"/>
  </exec>

 </target>

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you have an `exec` task in `startServer`. Add `spawn="true"` to the `exec`. Ant will then execute the command in the background and continue without waiting for it to complete.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Aaron you can use `exec` to do this, you can also use `waitfor` to test your connection.

```
<exec executable="${jboss.startup.bat}" spawn="true"/>
<echo>Waiting to start</echo>
<waitfor maxwait="10" maxwaitunit="second" checkevery="5000">
<!-- try to detect when the server has started -->
    <http url="${myurl}" />
</waitfor>
<echo>Started</echo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to be aware of the problems with exec'ing .bat files directly. Consult the manual page for the <exec> task for more information.